# Getting Application encountered a crash send report while running application outside Visual Studio Under Windows XP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, objectlistview

I'm developing disk catalog application using .net 3.5 framework. I used Objectlistview and TreeListView from ObjectListView library for representing folder structure. Application works without any problems under my Windows 7 x64 but when i tried it in Windows XP on VMware, application work without crashing when i debug it from Visual Studio 2010 but When i run application directly by double clicking it crash occurs and tell me to send error report to microsoft. Crash occurs when i click on folder shown in treelistview. it should show files and folders in objectlistview but it crashes every time on certain items. Same items when clicked in a vs2010 debugging session works absolutely fine. Expanding error generating items works without any crashes.

I tried obtaining excepion reort using Application.ThreadException but it doesn't report exception on certain items while some reports following exception in ObjectListView.

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: Try to run the application as admin.

Comment: Application doesn't work under xp admin account it runs fine on 7 on normal privileges.

Comment: Maybe this hotfix will help ? http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB975954

Comment: I figured out the problem and it's fix is described in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034552/getting-exceptions-on-x86-system-when-using-unmanaged-code-to-get-file-icon-usin